# Get JSON object and keys

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to display JSON data which is:

```
 var jsonData = ({
"respond": 1,
    "paging": {
    "stillmore": 0,
        "perpage": "10",
        "callpage": "1",
        "next": 0,
        "previous": 0,
        "pages": 1,
        "result": "2"
},
    "message": "",
    "result": [{
    "ID": "240",
        "post_title": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0430\u044f",
        "guid": "\/?post_type=transport&#038;p=240",
        "post_content": "",
        "post_author": "1",
        "post_date": "23\/01\/2014",
        "post_date_gmt": "23\/01\/2014",
        "comment_status": "closed",
        "ping_status": "closed",
        "post_name": "%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f",
        "post_modified": "23\/01\/2014",
        "post_modified_gmt": "23\/01\/2014",
        "post_content_filtered": "",
        "post_parent": "0",
        "menu_order": "0",
        "comment_count": "0",
        "featuredimage": "",
        "featuredthumb": "",
        "category": [

    ],
        "tags": [

    ],
        "author": [{
        "ID": "1",
            "user_login": "test",
            "user_nicename": "test",
            "user_email": "",
            "user_url": "",
            "user_registered": "04\/09\/2013",
            "display_name": "test",
            "role": {
            "editor": true
        },
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "test",
            "nickname": "test",
            "description": "",
            "avatar": "http:\/\/1.gravatar.com\/avatar\/1785a8ddcb564c1cac83da9fc26bc48e?s=96&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D96&amp;r=G",
            "aim": "",
            "jabber": "",
            "yim": "",
            "custom_fields": "ACF plugin needs to be enabled, Back to documentation for further information"
    }]
}, {
    "ID": "239",
        "post_title": "\u041f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u0430\u044f \u0433\u043e\u0440\u0431\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0438\u0446\u0430",
        "guid": "\/?post_type=transport&#038;p=239",
        "post_content": "",
        "post_author": "1",
        "post_date": "23\/01\/2014",
        "post_date_gmt": "23\/01\/2014",
        "comment_status": "closed",
        "ping_status": "closed",
        "post_name": "%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0",
        "post_modified": "23\/01\/2014",
        "post_modified_gmt": "23\/01\/2014",
        "post_content_filtered": "",
        "post_parent": "0",
        "menu_order": "0",
        "comment_count": "0",
        "featuredimage": "",
        "featuredthumb": "",
        "category": [

    ],
        "tags": [

    ],
        "author": [{
        "ID": "1",
            "user_login": "test",
            "user_nicename": "test",
            "user_email": "",
            "user_url": "",
            "user_registered": "04\/09\/2013",
            "display_name": "test",
            "role": {
            "editor": true
        },
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "test",
            "nickname": "test",
            "description": "",
            "avatar": "http:\/\/1.gravatar.com\/avatar\/1785a8ddcb564c1cac83da9fc26bc48e?s=96&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D96&amp;r=G",
            "aim": "",
            "jabber": "",
            "yim": "",
            "custom_fields": "ACF plugin needs to be enabled, Back to documentation for further information"
    }],
}]
});
```

on my page. What I need to get is **all** result.ID, result.post_title and result.author.ID, result.author.first_name, result.author.last_name.

My script is:

```
 $.ajax({
url: jsonData,
timeout: 3000,
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);

    $.each(data, function (i, post) {
        content += i.result.ID;
    });

    // console.log(content);
}
});
```

Please help me with my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LS3Pg/

I am new to JQUERY so will really appreciate your help here. Thank you.

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) This can help you.

Comment: @qqruza : problem with your json response, please correct it.

Comment: you have issue here `url: jsonData,` you have to put an url here not the json data variable. and your **jsonData is not a valid json**.

Comment: it supposed to be url, I just wanted to show the structure of the json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear the jsonData part of your code is what will be received from your AJAX call?

Here is sample code that tests the loop based on your jsonData object:

```
var content = "";
$.each(jsonData.result, function (i, post) {
    content += this.ID;
});
console.log(content);
```

Here is how it would look using a jQuery AJAX call.

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    var content = "";
    $.each(data.result, function (i, post) {
        content += this.ID;
    });
    console.log(content);
}, 'json');
```

It looks like you are using a `get` query. jQuery has a shortcut function for performing an `AJAX get` request, so I used that instead.

Other notes:

You can specify the data type in the `get` call at the end of the function. This way you don't have to use `JSON.parse`

Also the posts that are returned are held in the `result` variable, so you want to loop through that part of the data.

Using the jQuery.each function, the `this` variable will contain the post data you want as on object. From there you can use regular object access to get what you want. I just grabbed the ID here.

Here is a link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B364k/1/

Here is a link to a jsFiddle that grabs the author ID, first name, and last name: http://jsfiddle.net/B364k/2/

Here's the relevant part here:

```
console.log(this.author[0].ID);
console.log(this.author[0].first_name);
console.log(this.author[0].last_name);
```

To access the author, it is an array, so you need to use array access to access an author's data. This is probably because there can be multiple authors per post.

Comment: Thank you Gohn67, can you please amend my jsfiddle? I am sorry for being so not in details.

Comment: Sure, give a few minutes to remember how to make the AJAX work in jsFiddle. You need to do something slightly different for it to work in jsFiddle

Comment: Ok I added a jsFiddle. The link is in the answer. Note that the jsFiddle version is slightly different just to accomadate restrictions on AJAX requests in jsFiddle

Comment: Tell me if you need a better example for accessing your data. Right now it just concats your id values in one string...

Comment: Can you please help me to get result.author.ID, result.author.first_name, result.author.last_name as well please

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Alright I proved an update fiddle and explanation in my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gohn67, I have just a consideration if it is going to be more than one author? Shall I use this.author[1].ID for the next one or there is a line which will bring all authors details?

Comment: Yes, you would just loop through `this.author` array. Something like for(var i = 0; i < this.author.length; i++)...

Comment: I am sorry, can you please drop this line into the jsfiddle please. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are a star. Thanks a million